# Dynamically changing content of html div using callbacks

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a drop down menu with 2 options : `Village Amenities` and `Town Amenities`. If the user selects one of these options, I want the selected option to appear in the html div I have created below.

For this, I tried to use callbacks, but it doesn't seem to work.

My code is as follows :

```py
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([

        html.Div(children=[
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='input',
                options=[{'label': label, 'value': value} for label, value in zip(
                    ['Town Amenities', 'Village Amenties'], ['Town', 'Village'])],
                value="Town Amenties"
            ),
            html.Div(id='ouput'),
        ], style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
.......
```

And the callback code is as follows :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)
def update_value(input_data):
    return input_data
```

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output div in the layout has no set `children` prop. Dash struggles with unset default values, so you can fix this by setting it explicitly like this:

`html.Div(id='ouput', children=[]),`

The callback should work after that.